# Idiomatically insert items between two items in a sequence that fulfill a predicate?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

Say I have a predicate that takes two items and returns true of false.  I want to insert an item in between every consecutive pair in a sequence that returns true for the predicate.  I've come up with a couple of solutions but I was wondering what would be idiomatic way to do it functionally in Clojure?

Comment: I just submitted this to 4clojure - http://www.4clojure.com/problem/132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my try at it:

```
(defn interpose-predicated [pred in coll]
  (if (next coll)
    (->> coll
         (partition 2 1)
         (mapcat (comp next #(if (apply pred %) (interpose in %) %)))
         (cons (first coll)))
    coll))
```

Comment: Pretty and concise, but has a number of failure cases. What if `coll` is empty, or infinite? In the first case you return `(nil)`, and in the second you spend forever counting the sequence.

Comment: The nil case is handled properly, but I didn't completely think through the infinite sequence one. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I missed the nil-handling code. Funny given that it was exactly the same code causing the actual problem I noticed. I think you can switch `(nnext (seq coll))` to be just `(next coll)`, in fact - you have too many `next`s in there now, causing two-element collections to be returned without testing.

Comment: Yep, just noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: What's the benefit of doing
    `(comp next #(if (apply pred %) (interpose in %) %))`
vs
    `#(next (if (apply pred %) (interpose in %) %))`?

Comment: Just a style thing, really. I prefer to compose when possible, but they're equivalent.

Comment: This version isn't really as lazy as it could be - you force two elements of the input sequence even if no elements of the output sequence are ever forced.

Comment: Technically yes, but the `mapcat` alone will force a few elements. I don't think that's practically an issue.

Answer (score 4):

My first draft would be something like

```
(defn insert-between [pred inter coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [s (seq coll)]
     (cons (first s)
           (mapcat (fn [[left right]]
                     (if (pred left right)
                       [inter right]
                       [right]))
                   (partition 2 1 s))))))


user> (insert-between < :less [1 6 7 4 3])
(1 :less 6 :less 7 4 3)
```

Seems to work, but I'm special-casing the first element in an ugly way and I think you could get around that. The solution could definitely be improved, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It's the usual SO [clojure] race to come up with the most concise solution. :-) I usually don't win, but I learn a lot in the process. Anyway, here is my solution:

```
(defn interpose-p [[a b & _ :as s] d p]
  (when-not (empty? s)
    (if (and (not (nil? b)) (p a b))
      (cons a (cons d (interpose-p (rest s) d p)))
      (cons a (interpose-p (rest s) d p)))))

(interpose-p [1 2 3 2 1 2 3] "," <) 

(1 "," 2 "," 3 2 1 "," 2 "," 3)
```

**Update**: Even though the discussion is over, here is an updated solution taking into account everyone's comments. This time is should be fairly industrial strength assuming my understanding of lazy-seq is correct. It is templated off of the lazy-seq discussion [here](http://clojure.org/lazy).

```
(defn interpose-p
  [pred coll sep]
  (let [f (fn [c]
            (when-let [[a b & _ :as s] (seq c)]
              (if (and b (pred a b))
                (list* a sep (interpose-p pred (rest s) sep))
                (list* a (interpose-p pred (rest s) sep)))))]
    (lazy-seq (f coll))))
```

Comment: Things to look out for: your solution breaks when the seq contains `nil`s and when the list is infinitely long (or even just long enough to blow your stack). By using inbuilt sequence processing functions (`map`, `partition`, etc.) you usually get the benefit of laziness in the latter case.

Comment: BTW, this solution suffers from a couple of easily surmountable problems: 1/ It is not lazy-seqed 2/ It is not tail-call optimized, but both of those issues can be easily fixed.

Comment: The two improvements are mutually exclusive. You can't tail-recur lazily.

Comment: @mange A nil seq is not a problem. (empty? nil) is falsey not NPE. Agreed for the lazy seq issues which is easy fix by wrapping in lazy-seq.

Comment: No, but a seq containing `nil`s is a problem. `(interpose-p [1 nil nil] "," (constantly true))` => `(1 nil nil)`

Comment: @amalloy You would have to rejigger the code a bit to carry the resulting sequence in the argument list and use recur.

Comment: @JulienChastang I double-dog-dare you. It is possible to use lazy-seq and recur "near" each other, but there is no way to actually combine them - on each iteration of your loop you have to either recur or return a lazy sequence.

Comment: @amalloy I gave it another shot. See the update. I have spent a lot (too much) time today trying to understand the subtleties of lazy-seq. Anyway, as usual, I learned a lot.